# Function variants between different platforms when working with audio files

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2017, g++, posix

I was following a programming example for writing a small application the details of the application itself are not important. The issue or concern here is that within that application the provider is using the `POSIX` function `popen()`.

The line of code looks like this:

> ```
> static FILE* fp = popen( "resample mr1789800 r48000 | aplay -fdat 2>/dev/null", "w" );
> ```

And they were compiling their code with g++, I don't know what version they were using.

I am working on a Windows 7 x64 platform in Visual Studio 2017 with compiler set to latest drafted standard, all other options are default or standard settings. This is the general scenario.

All of the other code in the providers example is seems to be portable, this is the only piece of code that I've seen that is native to `POSIX` functionality.

It appears that they are using `popen` to load a file to an external program and by the looks from the code above it appears that the program is unix based `aplay`.

If I'm trying to mimic this behavior on Windows using Visual Studio what would be the required tools to use?

Will `_popen()` do the same thing, meaning are they nearly equivalent? If so, then the second half of the question is if `aplay` is the program that is opening the audio file, what options are available to me that are for windows that will handle the audio file the same way as the one that is found in a typical Unix type system? If not; what are the differences between the two and where would I go from here?

Comment: Yes, `_popen` is the POSIX standard function for doing POSIX `popen`. Yes, POSIX in both places, because both Windiows and Linux claim to be POSIX compatible environments.... They just have DIFFERENT variations on the theme... ;)

Comment: @Mats Petersson Okay that clears up the differences between platform versions with `popen` and windows `_popen`, but now I'm left with the dependency of `aplay` which is still unix...

Comment: I'm sure there are command-line tools to play audio in Windows, but I'm not entirely sure, and the usual way in Windows isn't to do that, but to send it to the audio device via native calls.

Comment: @Mats Petersson Yeah, normally if I'm working in say DirectX or OpenGL I would use DirectX's API for handling sound and have a loader function to load in mp3 or other audio type files, and if in OpenGL I would use OpenAL - ogg/vorbis. However in this particular program the audio is being synthesized from different wave forms that are being extracted out of a rom file. This is coming from a NES emulator.

Comment: He is using SDL version 1..  for handling the graphics (pixel sprites), now as for the audio that he processes he then passes it off to an external program for playback instead of using the SDL sdk to process it within the application itself.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1024792/is-there-a-windows-equivalent-to-the-linux-aplay-that-will-accept-a-bitstream

Comment: Are you trying to compile Bisqwit's NES emulator ?

Comment: @CuriousCat It's been a while since I've asked this question but in response to your comment; I believe so.